# How to return a value from a shell script in a perl script

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I have a perl script which requires a value from a shell script.

Following is the shell script (a.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
return_value(){
$value =$(///some unix command)
return $value
}
```

Following is the perl script:
///

```
my $answer= `sh  a.sh`;
print("the answer is $answer");
```

But its not working. please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
return_value(){
  value=$(///some unix command)
  echo "$value"
}

return_value
```

1. You can't have any spaces around `=` in a shell variable assignment.
2. Don't put `$` before the variable name that's the target of the assignment.
3. Perl's backticks capture the standard output of a command, so you have to echo the value (`return` sets the exit status of the function, it doesn't produce output).
4. You have to execute the function.
5. You should put `$value` in quotes in case it contains whitespace or filename wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

Just write

```
echo $value
```

in your bash code and the output will appear as the result of the backticks in the Perl code.

Answer (score 1):

Backqoutes substitute the stdout, not the return value (which is just an integer). If you used

```
echo $value
```

instead of `return $value` it would work as you expect. Simpler still would be

```
some unix command
```

as the single line in your bash script.